# How to update two database table through one ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajax-update

I have this nested JSON data object:

```
var obj = {  
   "ARCHIVE":"",
   "CREATED_BY":"Admin",
   "DESCRIPTION":"Some desc",
   "ID":"8d4d7a7f-52f5-434a-b66c-12088b32",
   "daySchedulesT":[  
      {  
         "DS_ID":"8d4d7a7f-52f5-434a-b66c-12088b32",
         "LANGUAGE_ID":"EN",
         "LONG_TEXT":"Some long desc"
      }
   ]
}
```

So I want to update two tables in my database. One table is **daySchedules** and the second is **daySchedulesT**.

Table daySchedules have fields:

- ID
- ARCHIVE
- CREATED_BY
- DESCRIPTION

where ID is primary key.

Table **daySchedulesT** have fields:

- DS_ID
- LANGUAGE_ID
- LONG_TEXT

where DS_ID is primary key.

There is also relationship between them, I have foreign key ID -> DS_ID. I want through one Ajax request update this two table.

Is that possible? And if it is, how I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried so far. I don't understand whether you are asking for ajax syntax or something else

Comment: you can run two update statements one after the other, or if your DB syntax supports it you might be able to use a join. The ajax part is sort of irrelevant, as long as you supply all the necessary data. Once you get to the server-side you can do whatever you like, assuming you have control of that code